# Unable to read the charecterstic in PLugin.Ble

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I need to get the correct characteristic to read and write in Bluetooth device but among two characteristics, Unable to read the values from read characteristic. Correct me if I'm wrong in code

```
        var services = await connectedDevice.GetServicesAsync();
        var serviceid = services[0].Id;
        var service = await 
        connectedDevice.GetServiceAsync(serviceid);
        var characteristics = await 
        service.GetCharacteristicsAsync();
        var characteristicread= await 
        service.GetCharacteristicAsync(characteristics[1].Id);
        var characteristicWrite = await 
        service.GetCharacteristicAsync(characteristics[0].Id);
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("LIST_DIR,audio");
        await characteristicWrite.WriteAsync(bytes);

        characteristicread.ValueUpdated += (s, ee) =>
            {
                var result = ee.Characteristic.Value;
                var stre = 
          System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);
               //i can't able read charecterstic
            };
            await characteristicread.StartUpdatesAsync();
```

### Expected behavior

after write value in write characteristic value should be updated in read characteristic

### Actual behavior

read characteristic value not updated

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this. First of all we need to check if the Characteristic has the **Read operation** in it for that you can download an app called **BLE scanner** from play store and connect to that device. When we connect to that BLE we will be able to see the available services and characteristics of the **BLE Peripheral**. And there we need to check which characteristics has **Read operation**. So if you try to do read characteristics for characteristics which doesn't have a read operation in peripheral it will give **exception read not permitted**.